# Open URL <a href... in my facebook app

Tags: facebook, url, iframe, href

I have my Facebook Page and my Facebook App (Iframe).
In that iFrame, I have a form (index.php), which send me to an other page : validation.php

The thing is : validation.php opens outside of my facebook app (outside of the canvas of Facebook app).

Can I build my URL in HTML to validation.php opens in the iFrame in my Facebook Page?
Like: app.facebook.com/id.... or something like that ??

Thks !

```
<form name="emvForm" id="emvForm" action="fb/validation.php" method="POST" target="_top">
```

How can I write my "action" URL to have validation.php display in my FB canvas app?

I switched "target" with _self and _parent attribute... but my page validation still appears outside FB.

My submit Button is :

```
<input type="button" value="Soumettre le formulaire" onClick="javascript:validForm();">
```

Comment: can you show some source? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp maybe?

Comment: Just remove the `target` attribute from the form element …

Comment: Don't works without target attribute. My validation page don't appears.